# margin+height makes the child to overflow even with box-sizing:border-box

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="main" class="row">
        <div id="header_wrapper" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2">
              <div id="header" class="mcard">header</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eeeded;
}

.container-fluid {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

.row {
  margin: 0px;
}

.row [class*="col-"] {
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  margin: 4rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

#header_wrapper {
  height: 20%;
}

#header {
  height: 100%;
}

.mcard {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWGapz?editors=110

In the above code, `#header` seems to overflow out of `#header_wrapper` because of `#header{height:100%;}` and `.mcard{margin:1rem;}` which adds up to more than the height of `#header_wrapper`and even though `box-sizing:border-box` has been applied, its still overflowing.

How do I avoid overflow without removing any margin or using hardcoded height in `px`?

Answer (score 0):

Change your header from `height 100%` to `height: auto`:

```
#header {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: so how should I apply the height of `#header` . It seems to collapse without height.

Comment: it seems `display:table-row` removes the margin

Comment: I'll try to find out another solution.